# Order ArrayList by Position

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of Player(s). The array is currently ordered in the player who've been logged on first, to the most recent one.

However, i want to sort the ArrayList from the Players positions, high to low. The position is stored in the Player class, retrieved by

```
player.getX();
```

I imagine i should have a loop with each item being added to a new ArrayList, but i can't quite figure out how to actually implement it.

How can i do this?

Loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < otherPlayers.size(); i++) {
    Player currentPlayer = otherPlayers.get(i);
}
```

Edit: Added loop example

Comment: Maybe it is useful to you:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either you make Player implementing `Comparable` and use `Collections.sort(players)` or you can directly create a comparator like this

```
    Collections.sort(players, new Comparator<Player>() {
        public int compare(Player o1, Player o2) {
            return o2.getX().compareTo(o1.getX());
        }
    });
```

Assuming `player.getX()` returns a `Integer`

**Edit**

Let's say you have your `List<Player>` named `otherPlayers` if you want to sort it directly without writing yourself a loop and the algorithm of sorting, you can rely on the Java built-in method `Collections.sort()` to sort it. But this means that either your class `Person` implements the `Comparable` interface, or you can pass an instance of `Comparator` as the second argument of the `Collections.sort()` method as done above.

The `Comparator.compare()` method takes two object and does return an integer that says if the first argument is lower than the second, equals or greater. This is how the sorting algorithm will know how to order the elements in your list. So, by creating a `Comparator` instance that compare the result of `Player.getX()` of two `Player` instances (the elements of your list), you are able to sort the original list on the position criteria as you asked for it.

Comment: +1 for  Comparator, it's less invasive than Comparable, Players can be ordered by more factors than position

Comment: I'm very new at Java, and i can't figure out how to implement that. I've added a run-through loop of the actual code. Could you perhaps extend your answer? Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! However, i'm getting "int cannot be dereferenced" when implementing it. I suppose "compare(Player o1, Player o2)" the o1 and o2 players doesn't have any coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

Sort it with `Collections#sort`.

```
List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
Collections.sort(players, new Comparator<Player>(){
                    public int compare(Player p1, Player p2){
                      return p1.getX().compareTo(p2.getX());
                    }
                 });
```

Comment: This assumes there's just 2 players, however there is an unknown amount of players. How would i implement that in your example? :-)

Comment: nope,it'll sort all players of your list. you can check this source [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.sort%28java.util.List%2Cjava.util.Comparator%29)

Comment: I'm getting "int cannot be dereferenced" using this!

Answer (score 0):

Player should implement `Comparable<Player>`

Then you have to implement a compareTo method in Player class.
After that sort using `Collections.sort(listOfPlayers);`

http://www.vogella.com/blog/2009/08/04/collections-sort-java/

Answer (score 0):

let Player implement

```
Comparable
```

Then implement

```
compareTo()
```

method and make comparison by positions.
Then you can make sort by means of

```
Collections.sort(yourList);
```

or

```
Collections.sort(yourList, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)`